# Fluent NHibernate Default Conventions

Tags: .net, fluent-nhibernate, conventions

I'm trying to find a resource that shows what default conventions Fluent NHibernate uses with no custom (user) conventions applied.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Conventions](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Conventions)

[Converting to new style conventions](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Converting-to-new-style-conventions)

Comment: These links define what a convention is, and how to create them.  I don't see a list of defaults?

Comment: The table in link 2 seems sufficient to me, try this: http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Available_conventions HTH.

Comment: Then my last idea would be to check the Source Code for conventions itself, http://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/tree/master/src/FluentNHibernate/Conventions/